# Jax-WS connect to any web service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

Apparently i have heard that you can connect to any web service with jax-ws using just few lines of code?. I have been trying to research something on the all knowing internet but i couldn't find anything. Does any one actually know what these few magic lines would be ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [JAX-WS Dynamic Client](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_jaxwsdynclient.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I think that this may be what i am looking for, i will examine it in a short while. Thanks